# docker deploy vs docker stack deploy

Tags: docker

According to the docs they are two same commands:
[docker stack deploy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/#/description) and [docker deploy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/deploy/#/description).

Is that the case or some information is hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The commands are synonyms, they hit the same backend API. Docker is in the first steps of transitioning from from `docker $verb` commands to `docker $noun $verb`, so you'll also see commands like `docker images` from before and `docker image ls`, or even `docker ps` and now `docker container ps`.

Comment: so that means I'm better off with `docker stack deploy`? or isn't the idea that `docker deploy` will eventually be removed.

Comment: Right now, `docker deploy` only exists in the experimental config, so I'd stick with `docker stack deploy`.